# camel proxy complains about wrong type

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-boot

I configured a spring boot based application to use remoting with activemq/jms. The listening part is running fine but I have problems implementing the sending part.

For the sender I went back to "classic" camel and spring because I found more working examples for this but still receive an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: 
Bean named 'myProxy' must be of type [foo.bar.YouNameIt], 
but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83]
```

This is the way I try to load the proxy definition:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/spring.xml");
YouNameIt youNameIt = context.getBean("myProxy", YouNameIt.class);
```

And this is the entry in the spring.xml:

```
<camel:proxy id="myProxy"
    serviceInterface="foo.bar.IYouNameIt"
    serviceUrl="activemq:queue:site12345" />
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: in your spring config u create the proxy for IYouNameIt, in the code examples you use YouNameIt. Is one of them wrong? Or is that your problem?

Comment: In all the examples I see the proxy needs to be based on an interface. Personally I would prefer a solution without an interface but the specs say I need it.

Comment: It would be more correct to use the interface in your code as well. You can only cast the proxy to an interface cause the proxy is implementing that interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the interface `IYouNameIt` and not the implementation class `YouNameIt`:

```
IYouNameIt youNameIt = context.getBean("myProxy", IYouNameIt.class);
```

See [here](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-jmsremoting.html#Tutorial-JmsRemoting-TutorialonSpringRemotingwithJMS) for a full Spring remoting example.